# use intent and the putextra method to pass the pos in the following code?

Tags: android

Mainactivity.java
this is the mainactivity which calls the three methods

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        public TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postp);
        public Spinner catspinner,planspinner1,planspinner2;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle mbfSplash) {
            super.onCreate(mbfSplash);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            chooseCategory();
            chooseone();
            choosetwo();
    }

public void chooseCategory() {

        catspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.catspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.states_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        catAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        catspinner.setAdapter(catAdapter);
        catspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new planOnClickListener());
    }



private void chooseone(){
        planspinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        List<String> planlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        planlist.add("Mandu");
        planlist.add("Chanderi");
        planlist.add("Jabalpur");
        planlist.add("Orccha");
        planlist.add("Bhopal");
        ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist);
        planAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        planspinner1.setAdapter(planAdapter1);

    }

private void choosetwo(){

        planspinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        List<String> planlist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        planlist1.add("Premier Plan");
        planlist1.add("The Executive Plan");
        planlist1.add("Business Circle Plan");
        planlist1.add("Business Diamond Plan");
        ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist1);
        planAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        planspinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);
}




public class planOnClickListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                               long id) {
        final int p = pos;
        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

        if (pos==0){
            choosePersonalPlan();
        }else if (pos==1){
            chooseLargeBusPlan();
        } else if (pos==2){
            chooseSmallMedPlan();
        }


        /*Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent("com.example.android.testing.SecondActivity"));
         intent.putExtra("value",str);
        //---set the data to pass back---
        //data.setData(Uri.parse(str));
        //setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        //---closes the activity---
        //finish();
        startActivity(intent);*/
    }




    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

the choosecategory() method gives a selected item from spinner

the next method are choosed on the basis of the first spinner item(i.e. second spinner is dependent on the spinner no. one)

second method maybe choose 1 or choose 2

the method is choosen by the help of the onItemSelected method in the planOnClickListener

thanks for the help...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: tryin to pass the value of pos

Comment: use intent to second activity

Comment: In the intent which's commented, you've not passed the position, you can do it like this.  
`new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class).putExtra("position", p);`

Comment: i tried but does not worked out

Comment: the emulator just crashes it shows a message saying Unfortunately, Testing has stopped

Comment: what happens in log?

Comment: can you help me with getting the value of planspinner2

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your extra to your intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i know that but when i use it it does not work inside the planOnClickListener class