# How to return a value with the planOnClickListener class in java?

Tags: android

```
public class planOnClickListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
        final int p = pos;
        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        if (pos==0){
            choosePersonalPlan();
        }else if (pos==1){
            chooseLargeBusPlan();
        } else if (pos==2){
            chooseSmallMedPlan();
        }

        /*Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent("com.example.android.testing.SecondActivity"));
          intent.putExtra("value",str);
        //---set the data to pass back---
        //data.setData(Uri.parse(str));
        //setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        //---closes the activity---
        //finish();
        startActivity(intent);*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
}
```

I need to get value of the pos outside the onItemSelected method, and pass via an intent to the another activity. How to do so?

Comment: if want the complete code

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140205/use-intent-and-the-putextra-method-to-pass-the-pos-in-the-following-code/42140323#42140323

Comment: why your intent doesn't work? you can do it with [intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Types).

Comment: i can't get the value from it and the message is shown inside the emulator that Unfortunately, Testing has stopped

Comment: give me log error please

Comment: there is no error but maybe i think i was doing it wrong

Comment: send the part you create your intent and the part that you receive it